# I'm getting a Cannot read property of 'exercises' of undefined error when trying to map my props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, react-props

Here's my "database" that I'm using,

index.js:

```
const workoutPlan = {
  ID: 1,
  Name: "My Workout Plan",
  workout: {
    day: "Monday",
    exercises: [
      {
        Name: "Bench Press",
        sets: [
          {
            set: 1,
            weight: 135,
            rep: 10
          },
          {
            set: 2,
            weight: 145,
            rep: 8
          }
        ]
      },

      {
        Name: "Deadlift",
        sets: [
          {
            set: 1,
            weight: 135,
            rep: 10
          },
          {
            set: 2,
            weight: 145,
            rep: 8
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Which then in my WorkoutPlan.js file, I'm passing the properties of the workoutPlan to my Workout.js child.

WorkoutPlan.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Workout from "./Workout";
import axios from "axios";

class WorkoutPlan extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      workoutPlan: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("/api/workout-plan")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ workoutPlan: response.data });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { workoutPlan } = this.state;
    // const workoutPlan = this.state.workoutPlan;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{workoutPlan.Name}</h1>
        <Workout workout={workoutPlan.workout} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WorkoutPlan;
```

In my Workout.js file, I'm trying to only map the exercises property of WorkoutPlan.workout.exercises. However, when I run this code, I'm running into a 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'exercises' of undefined

What am I doing wrong in this Child?

Workout.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Exercise from "./Exercise";

// const Workout = props => {
//   props.workout.exercises.map(exercises => {
//     return (
//       <div>
//         <h2>"Workout for {props.day}"</h2>
//         <Exercise exercises={exercises} />
//       </div>
//     );
//   });
// };

function Workout(props) {
  props.workout.exercises.map(exercises => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>"Workout for {props.day}"</h2>
        <p>{exercises.Name}</p>
        <Exercise exercises={exercises} />
      </div>
    );
  });
}

export default Workout;
```

I've commented out the const, as I'm told that they're both methods are interchangeable. But if someone could actually provide some insight on how to do it on both methods, I'd be so grateful.
The error is specifically referring to

```
  props.workout.exercises.map(exercises => {
```

in my Workout.JS file

Answer (score 2):

On the first render, the `props.workout` value passed to the `Workout` is `undefined` because looking in the parent component `WorkoutPlan` the default value for `this.state.workoutPlan` is `{}` so calling `workoutPlan.workout` will be `undefined.

There are two approaches, in the parent don't render this component if the value is `undefined`. Or, in the child, handle the value of `undefined`.

Handling in the parent:

```
  render() {
    const { workout } = this.state.workoutPlan;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{workoutPlan.Name}</h1>
        {workout && <Workout workout={workout} />}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Or, in the child:

```
function Workout(props) {
  // Early return if falsy value is passed (eg: undefined, null)
  if (!props.workout) return null;

  return props.workout.exercises.map(exercises => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>"Workout for {props.day}"</h2>
        <p>{exercises.Name}</p>
        <Exercise exercises={exercises} />
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Note, you also need to `return` the `props.workout.exercises.map` value.